# maven javadoc overview.html can't update overview-summery.html

Tags: html, maven, javadoc

I write overview.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>API Overview</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    Short overview of the API.
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and put it in `project/src/main/java`,and I add these codes in pom.xml:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
        <configuration>

          <overview>${basedir}/overview.html</overview>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

but the overview-summary.xml still can't update.
I read this guide and everything looks fine, why it can't update?
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/javadoc-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

`${basedir}` refers to the root directory of your project, thus the javadoc plugin cannot find the file at the location indicated in your pom. If you keep this pom.xml, move your file overview.html to `<project>\overview.html`.

Comment: I move overview.html to '<project>/overview.html' but it doesn't work.

Comment: which maven command do you use ? in your pom.xml as you put the javadoc plugin in the `<reporting/>` section, you need to use `mvn site`. Did you try to put the javadoc plugin in the `<build/>`section and use `mvn javadoc:javadoc` to obtain a stand alone javadoc ?